# Angular Mat-Menu incompatible with Nx’s Storybook plugin

Tags: angular, angular-material, storybook, nrwl, angular-storybook

I’m having issue with the integration between Nx’s Storybook plug-in and Angular Material 12’s `mat-menu` component.
When I trigger the menu, its `DOM` node is outside the `storybook`’s `iframe` component, hence missing the component’s styling.
How can I deal with this issue?
Thank :)